# Show and hide dynamically fields in Django form

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I have a form in Django:

views.py:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ...)
    list1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(...)
    list2 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(...)
```

home.htm:

```
<td valign='top'>{{ form.type }}</td>
<td valign='top'>{{ form.list1 }}</td>
<td valign='top'>{{ form.list2 }}</td>
<td valign='top'><input type="submit" value="Find" /></td>
```

I want the list1 element to be shown and the list2 to be hide if type is 1 and vice versa in case type is 2. I want them to be hide and shown dynamically without reloading the page or any interaction with the server.

I believe Javascript could be useful here, but I don't know it.

Comment: Do you intend to make this work with or without any further interaction with the server? If you don't want the server to be involved, Javascript is indeed the only way to go. I'd be glad to give an example for both cases, just let us know which method you prefer.

Comment: Without, using jscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
<script>function Hide()
{
    if(document.getElementById('mainselect').options[document.getElementById('mainselect').selectedIndex].value == "1")
    {
         document.getElementById('a').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('b').style.display = '';
    }else
    {
         document.getElementById('a').style.display = '';
         document.getElementById('b').style.display = 'none'
    }
}
</script>
<td valign='top'><select id="mainselect" onchange="Hide()"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></td>
<td valign='top' id='a'>{{ form.list1 }}</td>
<td valign='top' id='b'>{{ form.list2 }}</td>
<td valign='top'><input type="submit" value="Find" /></td>
```

Comment: Crap - I had ( instead of {.  Try it again.

Comment: This implies that the server or more precisely the template context knows about the type choice the user has taken.

Comment: form.type is a place holder for the templating system.  The client will not see form.type.  By the looks of his code he wants to hide based on the server value form.type.

Comment: No, I want if a user select type 1, list1 is shown, if he switches to type 2, list2 is shown and so on, without any interaction with the server.

Comment: I've edited my answer to hide based on the user's selection of a drop down list.

Comment: The Javascript solution is valid, the notion about the ``form.type`` value however is not correct. If you declare a field named "type" in a form, the corresponding ``form.type`` property in a template context that contains the form points at the ``render`` method of the very same field. Ergo ``{{ form.type }}`` renders the field as defined in the Form class.

Comment: How to pass mainselect parameter value to Django view?

Comment: Got it, had to add 'name' attribute to it. It's working now! Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 6):

This is an adaption of Andrew's Javascript solution, using Django forms the way you'd usually expect.

The form in Django / Python:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ((1, 'One'), (2, 'Two')))

    # Use any form fields you need, CharField for simplicity reasons
    list1 = forms.CharField()
    list2 = forms.CharField()
```

The template, assuming an instance of `SearchForm` got passed to the template context with the name 'form':

```
<script>
function Hide() {
    if(document.getElementById('id_type').options[document.getElementById('id_type').selectedIndex].value == "1") {
         document.getElementById('id_list1').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('id_list2').style.display = '';
    } else {
         document.getElementById('id_list1').style.display = '';
         document.getElementById('id_list2').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('id_type').onchange = Hide;
};
</script>

<div>
    {{ form.type.label_tag }}{{ form.type }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form.list1.label_tag }}{{ form.list1 }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form.list2.label_tag }}{{ form.list2 }}
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see that it will also hide the label.

Comment: @ismailsunni if you jquery can hide the label with: $('#id_list1').parent().hide(); In pure javascript may use .parentElement