# How to hide fields in Django form depending on the selected category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make sure that when you add a new ad, choosing a category, hiding unnecessary fields in the form. I understand that this is done in JS, but for the time being I don’t understand well, so I’ll tell you if anyone is good at it.
For example, I want the "Stage" to disappear when selecting "Houses and land":

[image]

Listing model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
  realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Риелтор')
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
  region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Область')
  city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Город')
  district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Район')
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Заголовок')
  landmark = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Ориентир')
  description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
  stage = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Этаж')
  rooms = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Количество комнат')
```

forms.py

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        exclude = ('realtor',)
```

Form in template:

```
<form method="POST"  novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% bootstrap_form form %}
   <input type="submit" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
</form>
```

I looked in the browser structure of the form in the template:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_category">Категория</label>
<select name="category" class="form-control" title="" required id="id_category">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="1">Квартиры</option>
  <option value="2">Коммерческое</option>
  <option value="3">Дома и участки</option>
</select></div>
```

The field structure I want to hide:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="id_stage">Этаж</label>
   <input type="number" name="stage" value="0" 
   class="form-control" placeholder="Этаж" title="" id="id_stage">
</div>
```

I tried to do this, but it does not work yet:

```
<script>
    $('#id_category').change(function () {
      var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
      var valueSelected = $(this).val();

      if (valueSelected === 3){
          $('#id_rooms').hide();
      } else {
          $('#id_rooms').show();
      }
    });
  </script>
```

If you know, tell me, please, or an example of how it is done. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In a  tag in your template, you'll need to use javascript to add an event listener on change of the first field.

In that event listener, if the value is the "selected category" use javascript to hide or show fields in the form.

For example if I had a form like this:

```
<form>
     <select id="select">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
     <input id="field">Input Field</input>
</form>
```

In JQuery, this would look something like this:

```
$('#select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;

    if (valueSelected === 1){
        $('#field').hide();
    } else {
        $('#field').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: But I have django form and I have to write something else in the view.py.

Comment: It should still work, since Django is generating the form html inside the template. 
Try inspecting the form in your browser to see the DOM structure.

Here's another example of what you are trying to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136657/show-and-hide-dynamically-fields-in-django-form