# show/hidden field forms with condition in django

Tags: javascript, django, templates, django-forms

I have trouble when trying to hide and show form field in django.
My code works well when showing form field

```
<label class="col-md-8" id="sotien">{{form.so_tien}}</label>
```

However I failed when trying hide the field with condition. If ma_code=="ptp", form.so_tien is hidden and vice versa

my forms:

```
class AddReportForm(forms.Form):
list_ma_code=(
    ("skipcall","SKIP CALL"),
    ("ptp","PTP"),
)
ma_code=forms.ChoiceField(label="Mã code",choices=list_ma_code,widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))

so_tien=forms.IntegerField(label="Số tiền",widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "type":"number"}),required=False, initial=0)
```

my html

```
 <label class="col-md-8" id="id_ma_code">{{ form.ma_code }}</label>
 <label class="col-md-8" id="sotien">{{form.so_tien}}</label>
```

my js

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
function Hide() {
    if(document.getElementById('id_ma_code').options[document.getElementById('id_ma_code').selectedIndex].value == "ptp") {
         document.getElementById('sotien').style.display='none';
    } else {
         document.getElementById('sotien').style.display='none';
    }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> { 
window.addEventListener("load", Hide);
};
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
{var el = document.getElementById("id_ma_code"); 
el.addEventListener("click", Hide);
};
</script>
```

I tried another script, but it still fail

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function Hide() {
    let id_ma_code = document.getElementById("id_ma_code");
    let sotien = document.getElementById("sotien");
    let labelsotien = document.getElementById("labelsotien");
    id_ma_code.addEventListener("change", function () {
            if (id_ma_code.value === "ptp") {
                sotien.style.display='none';
                labelsotien.style.display='none';
            } else {
                sotien.style.display='none';
                labelsotien.style.display='none';
            }
        });
}

</script>
```

When I check `console.log(Hide())` it showed undefined - It is not defined
There was not any error, but the code didnt work. Even if I change all to hide, it didnt hide anything

I read some questions but fail to resolve my issue

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136657/show-and-hide-dynamically-fields-in-django-form

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893040/how-to-hide-fields-in-django-form-depending-on-the-selected-category
```

I updated my code
Thanks for your reading and supporting me

Comment: To hide `document.getElementById('sotien').style.display='none';` and to show `document.getElementById('sotien').style.display='block';` and add paranthesis to `Hide()` function when calling

Comment: `.show()` and `.hide()` are jQuery functions, not vanilla JS ones.

Comment: I updated my code but it didnot work @Ahtisham

Comment: What value does this return `if(document.getElementById('id_ma_code').options[document.getElementById('id_ma_code').selectedIndex].value` and does the control go inside Hide ?

Comment: @Ahtisham sorry for asking a stupid question, how can I get the return. I just modified the formular and I dont know how to print it out

Comment: It is basic use `console.log(your formula);`

Comment: there is an error when I use console.log(Hide()) `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')
    at Hide ((index):329)
    at <anonymous>:1:13`

Comment: @Ahtisham when I check document.getElementById('id_ma_code'), it returns null. I think this is the issue